# Javascript countdown on first keyup

Tags: javascript, countdown

```js
let userInput = document.getElementById('userInput');
const countdown = document.getElementById('countdown'); //DOM for change the html value
let countTime = 10;

userInput.addEventListener('keyup',function(){
    countdown.innerHTML = countTime;
    let mundur = setInterval(function(){
        countTime -= 1;
        if (countTime <= 0 ){
            clearInterval(mundur);
            countTime = 0;
        }
        countdown.innerHTML = countTime;
    },1000);
})
```

Please help me! I want to make a countdown when the user inputs, like https://10fastfingers.com . Countdown event will run on the first time keyup and not run again on next keyup. But in next keyup, the countdown not working properly.
Please help me

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please copy and paste your code in a code-block.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was newbie stackoverflow user, and now I just fixed it :)
Thanks bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell the event listener to only fire once by adding an object to the third argument {once:true}

```
addEventListener('keyup', function(){},{once:true})
```

documentation to everything about event listeners:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Also, you should copy and paste your code, not an image. It makes it easier for people to potentially test or edit for you.
Images of errors are acceptable and often easier to read IMO.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, very simple and efficient.
Maybe I still haven't learned much javascript language.
Thank you very much bro.

Comment: @gunzxx No problem, there is so many little hidden things in Javascript it seems. Just keep plugging away, learning more every week. Thats all we can do as developers lol

Answer (score 0):

Just check it is first

```
let isFirst = true;
let currentTimer = 0;

document.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
    if (isFirst) {
       isFirst = false;

       //start count
       currentTimer = 10000;
       console.log('time left', currentTimer);
       let it = setInterval(() => {
          currentTimer -= 1000;
          console.log('time left', currentTimer);

          if (!currentTimer) {
             clearInterval(it);
          }

       }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use "removeEventListener"
In code below timer will start on the first keyup and next keyups won't work until it reaches zero

```
    //<p id="timer">1:00</p> HTML//
 
    const timer = document.querySelector("#timer");

    document.addEventListener("keydown", startTimer);

    function startTimer() {
       setTimer();
       this.removeEventListener("keydown", startTimer);
    }

    function setTimer() {
       let counter = 60;
       const timerId = setInterval(() => {
           counter--;
           timer.innerHTML = `0:${counter}`;
           if (counter == 0) {
           clearInterval(timerId);
           document.addEventListener("keydown", startTimer);
           }
       }, 1000);
    }
```